# What's wrong with this SKShapeNode gradient coloring code?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skshapenode, sktexture

I'm trying to create gradient colored `SKShapeNode`.

I found the code below from *[theGoogle](https://craiggrummitt.wordpress.com/2015/03/24/skshapenode-gradient/)* but it only works when color1 is black, e.g. defined as follows:

```
CIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
```

The second color can be anything.

```
enum GradientDirection {
    case up
    case left
    case upLeft
    case upRight
}
extension SKTexture {
    convenience init(size:CGSize,color1:CIColor,color2:CIColor,direction:GradientDirection = .up) {
        let coreImageContext = CIContext(options: nil)
        let gradientFilter = CIFilter(name: "CILinearGradient")
        gradientFilter!.setDefaults()
        var startVector:CIVector
        var endVector:CIVector
        switch direction {
        case .up:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width/2, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: size.width/2, y: size.height)
        case .left:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height/2)
            endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height/2)
        case .upLeft:
            startVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: size.height)
        case .upRight:
            startVector = CIVector(x: 0, y: 0)
            endVector = CIVector(x: size.width, y: size.height)

        }
        gradientFilter!.setValue(startVector, forKey: "inputPoint0")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(endVector, forKey: "inputPoint1")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(color1, forKey: "inputColor0")
        gradientFilter!.setValue(color2, forKey: "inputColor1")
        let cgimg = coreImageContext.createCGImage(gradientFilter!.outputImage!, fromRect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
        self.init(CGImage:cgimg)
    }
}
```

I want the color one to be something else than black. I can't figure out what's wrong with this code. I define the `SKShapeNode` as follows:

```
let textureSize = CGSize(width: shapeNode.frame.width, height: shapeNode.frame.height)
let bottomColor = CIColor.init(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1.0)
let topColor = CIColor.init(red: 225, green: 255, blue: 255, alpha: 1.0)
let shapeTexture = SKTexture(size:textureSize, color1:bottomColor, color2:topColor, direction:GradientDirection.up)
shapeNode.fillTexture = shapeTexture
self.addChild(shapeNode)
```

All help appreciated!

Comment: RGB values for `CIColor` should be in [0, 1]. 255 is not a valid value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RGB values for CIColor should be in [0, 1]. 255 is not a valid value.